# Power off when cable is pulled using a timer: Boot up functionality

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a small project at the moment, and part of the functionality is to have the device shut off if the power cable is disconnected and a timer reaches zero.

Power Cable Off -> Timer Starts

Power Cable Connected -> Timer Resets(cancel).
Power Cable Connected when device is off -> Device boots up.

The problem arises when the device boots up, the app itself crashes. I've noticed two exceptions thrown.

1. Trying to cancel a countdown timer that is null.
2. PowerConnection Reciever is null. (Happens straight away on boot).

I was able to mitigate the first issue by making the countdown timer a static variable, and as opposed to instaniating it in onCreate(), I now do it as well in PowerConnectionReciever as per the code below.

```
 public static class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
 {
    @Override
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
    {
        if( intent.getAction().equals( "android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" ) )
        {
            if( lShutdownTimer != null )
            {
                lShutdownTimer.start();
            }
            else
            {
                lShutdownTimer = createTimer( 50000, 30000 );
                lShutdownTimer.start();

            }


            Toast.makeText( context.getApplicationContext(), "Power cable disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
        else if( intent.getAction().equals( "android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" ) )
        {
            Toast.makeText( context.getApplicationContext(), "Power cable connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            if( lShutdownTimer != null )
                lShutdownTimer.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Create timer is just a static class that returns a CountDownTimer:

```
private static CountDownTimer createTimer( int aLimit, int aInterval )
{
    return new CountDownTimer( aLimit, aInterval )
    {
        @Override
        public void onTick( long millisUntilFinished )
        {
            Toast.makeText( mContext.getApplicationContext(), "50 Seconds until power off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {
            powerOff();

        }
    };
}
```

If someone could point me in the right direction as to how to handle bootup (so it works straight away), that would be fantastic. I've looked at a few options, but most seem relatively domain specific with services.

Following on, the app is fine when I boot up, if all code regarding the timer is removed.

This is the exception given:

```
                                             Process: MYAPP, PID: 7391
                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                 at MYAPP.MainActivity$1.onTick(MainActivity.java:349)
                                                 at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:133)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7399)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: `PowerConnection Reciever is null.` in which part of code? you don't use an instance of `PowerConnection` in your code. `countdown timer that is null` - you check for null before cancelling, so it can't be null.

Comment: Added the exception thrown

Comment: your exception means that you newer set `mContext`, therefore it is null.

Comment: MainActivity.java:349 context is null

Comment: Sure, it get's set in onCreate (obviously not when the device boots), how how does one handle when it does? And why would it all of a sudden continue working without the timer?

Comment: BroadcastReceiver has it's own context. Use it's context, pass it in your timer, and use it in your timer. `why would it all of a sudden continue working without the timer` - what continues working? does it turn off, or does not?

Comment: Ah okay, but there doesn't seem to a parameter for CountDownTimer to take a context? 

If I remove all the timer code, and just have the Toast, it continues to output the toast fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks to Vlad Matvienko, changing create timer to take a context to use with the Toast solved the issue.

```
private static CountDownTimer createTimer( int aLimit, int aInterval )
{
    return new CountDownTimer( aLimit, aInterval, context )
    {
        @Override
        public void onTick( long millisUntilFinished )
        {
            Toast.makeText( context .getApplicationContext(), "50 Seconds until power off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {
            powerOff();

        }
    };
}
```

It takes the context from onRecieve(), and uses that within the broadcast receiver.